# Self-join to find Customers IDs not in Item (Purchase)

Tags: sql, join, self-join

I have a table with two columns: ProductID and CustomerID

Everytime a specific customer (CustomerID) purchases a specific product (denoted by a specific ProductID), the table records that.

ProductID can appear multiple times, matched with a different customerID (and customers may purchase a product multiple times).

| ProductID | CustomerID |
| --- | --- |
| 1111111 | 14567 |
| 2222222 | 17890 |
| 3333333 | 17890 |
| 4444444 | 17890 |
| 5555555 | 14567 |
| 5555555 | 17890 |

Is there a way two pull out the customers (CustomerID) who bought a certain product (ProductID) but did not purchase another product (ProductID).

Currently, I have

```
select a.CustomerID
from iread a, iread b
where a.CustomerID in ({{ProductID}}) and b.CustomerID not in ({{ProductID}})
and a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID
```

which just gives me the ProductID back... I think it may have to do with this part:

```
where a.CustomerID in ({{ProductID}}) and b.CustomerID not in ({{ProductID}})
```

Any help/solutions welcome! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a having clause and case expression to filter your aggregated records would help you to filter across multiple rows. This would also be less expensive than a self-join.

Eg

```sql
SELECT
    CustomerID
FROM
    iread
WHERE 
    ProductID IN (<included_comma_separated_product_ids_to_be_considered_which_are_desired_and_not_desired>)
GROUP BY
    CustomerID
HAVING
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN ProductID=<include_desired_product_id> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) > 0 AND
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN ProductID=<include_not_desired_product_id> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) = 0
```

Below is an example where we try to find customers who purchased `5555555` but not `1111111` based on the sample data you shared.

**Aggregated Results for Debugging Purposes**

```
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN ProductID=5555555 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) as desired_product,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN ProductID=1111111 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) as undesired_product
FROM
    iread
WHERE 
    ProductID IN (5555555,1111111)
GROUP BY
    CustomerID;
```

| CustomerID | desired_product | undesired_product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14567 | 1 | 1 |
| 17890 | 1 | 0 |

---

**Using Having and Case expressions to retrieve desired customers**

```
SELECT
    CustomerID
FROM
    iread
WHERE 
    ProductID IN (5555555,1111111)
GROUP BY
    CustomerID
HAVING
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN ProductID=5555555 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) > 0 AND
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN ProductID=1111111 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) = 0;
```

| CustomerID |
| --- |
| 17890 |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kkWizDDWafmmz1KYK7kzd8/1)

**Edit 1:** *I have modified the examples above to include a where clause. This should take advantage of indexes on the columns used in the where clause if indexes are available on the table.*

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hello! Thanks, the having and case expression helps! However, since there's so many customers, it does load a little slower. Do you think separating it out by a larger category (ex. the table also has a larger "category" section that products are binned in) would help it run faster?

Comment: You may try that approach and see if there are any improvements. I cannot provide a definite answer as I will be unable to replicate your environment. I have however updated the answer to include a `WHERE` clause. If there are indexes on your table for `ProductId` or `Category`, this may speed up your query. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thank you! that was perfect~